# react-native android mediaplayer streams https but not http (but android exoplayer works)

Tags: android, react-native, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I am trying to debug an issue on a react-native mobile app that does media streaming.
When I use the default android mediaplayer, it streams https but not http.
However when I substitue android exoplayer by adding the following to settings.gradle, it successfully streams both http and https.

```
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')
include ':app'
```

The parameter `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` is set in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Any ideas why the default android mediaplayer seems to be blocking http streams?